# How to break overridden method if it's base method fails?

Tags: java, oop

I have a method called `validateData` in my `Parent` class. In my `Child` class I override that method adding some additional functionality. If everything is ok, I need to call method called `sendData()`. Here is my code in Java:

```
  public class Parent {

    protected int sum;
    protected double commission;

    protected void validateData() {
        if (!isSumWrittenCorrectly()) {
            return;
        }

        performData();
    }

    private boolean isSumWrittenCorrectly() {
        if (sum < 100) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    protected void performData() {
        commission = sum * 0.02;
    }


}


class Child extends Parent {
    private String email;

    @Override
    protected void validateData() {
        super.validateData();

        if (!isEmailWrittenCorrectly()) {
            return;
        }

        performData();
    }

    @Override
    protected void performData() {
        super.performData();


        sendData(email, commission, sum);

    }
}
```

So, the problem is, even if `sum` can be incorrectly written, the `performData` of child class can be called anyway. How to prevent this? I had an idea that `validateData` needs to return `boolean` and in my child class I check through `super` keyword. But it is a bad idea I think. So, how to break overridden method if it's base method fails?

Comment: I would say you should change your design. As of now it's impossible for the caller of the method to know whether the validation was successful or not. Adding a boolean as return type would be a way to fix this and I do not think it's a bad idea at all.

Comment: But in that case, I need to call validation method of base class from child class using super keyword. Does not it lead to decoupling? I mean, is reusing the method of base class in child class a good idea?

Comment: You have a bad design here. You should not call perfomData inside the validateData() method because validate should only validate and do not do anything else. Other solution would be to throw an exception instead of 'return' and if you need to catch it, catch it outside of the classes.

Comment: @abay reusing a base method via super keyword is fine

Comment: You probably want to do what lub0v suggests. Have a `boolean validate` method that does nothing but... validate it. And then you can do further things with it afterwards.

Comment: Also reusing a base-method with the super keyword is not just fine but even widely used and a common thing. You actually want to do that in many cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you let your `performData()` check if the validation is ok, that makes it a lot easier. You might also want to make `performData()` `public` to be accessible outside the class.

```
public class Parent {

    protected int sum;
    protected double commission;

    protected boolean validateData() {
        return isSumWrittenCorrectly();
    }

    private boolean isSumWrittenCorrectly() {
        if (sum < 100) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected void performData() {
        if(!validateData()) {
            return;
        }
        commission = sum * 0.02;
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {

    private String email;

    @Override
    protected boolean validateData() {
        if(!super.validateData()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isEmailWrittenCorrectly()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void performData() {
        super.performData();
        if(!validateData()) {
            return;
        }
        sendData(email, commission, sum);
    }
}
```

In the end, it might also be easier to throw an exception in case of validation failing, that will save some `true` `false` comparisions.

```
public class Parent {

    protected int sum;
    protected double commission;

    protected void validateData() {
        if(!isSumWrittenCorrectly()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("sum is not correct");
        }
    }

    private boolean isSumWrittenCorrectly() {
        if (sum < 100) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }


    protected boolean performData() {
        validateData();
        commission = sum * 0.02;
    }
}


class Child extends Parent {

    private String email;

    @Override
    protected boolean validateData() {
        super.validateData();
        if (!isEmailWrittenCorrectly()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("email is not correct")
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void performData() {
        validateData();
        super.performData();
        sendData(email, commission, sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is an often seen technique. Unfortunately relying on the need to call `super.validateData`.

```
public class Parent {
    protected boolean validateData() { ... }

public class Child extends Parent {
    protected boolean validateData() {
        if (!super.validateData()) {
            return false;
        }
        ...
    }
```

Alternatively you can split the functionality in

- offered service (`public final validateData`) and
- requirement to provide (`protected dataValidate/onValidateData`).

So:

```
public class Parent {
    public final void validateData() {
        boolean valid = dataValidated();
        ...
    }
    protected boolean dataValidated() {
        return true;
    }

public class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    protected boolean dataValidated() {
        ...
    }
```

This allows the parent class to control the behavior, and for instance provide arguments to the protected callback method.

Answer (score 0):

when coming to `method overriding` JVM compiles `parent method` in `compile time` and at `runtime` it executes `child method`. that means child class overrides the parent class methods.

Your `validateData` method doesn't return `boolean` because its `return` type is `void`.

If you want to prevent the child method from executing then, create an object of `parent` like `parent p = new parent();` then the child method won't execute.